# customize theme don't show actionbar

Tags: android, user-interface, android-actionbar

here is [full code](https://github.com/roroco/vst/tree/cannot-show-actionbar), here is my theme definition

res/styles.xml

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@android:style/Widget.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When targeting API 20 (`L`) and higher, you should use an `ActionBarActivity` (from `android.support.v7.app`) instead of a `FragmentActivity`. Your `ActionBar` will then show up.

Comment: you're right, can you tell me how to adjust actionbar height, I look like so big

Comment: @anxvonial You'll have to create a specific style for your `ActionBar` (inheriting from `Widget.ActionBar` for example), put inside of it something like that: `<item name="android:height">48dp</item>` (`48dp` being the default size, AFAIR)

Answer (score 0):

```
   <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

If I understood right, here's the code. It will set the app to be fullscreen. If you don't want that, just use

```
  <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```